# Dynamically create the where condition in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a created a form that shows the list box with around 30 local table on same access database.
i have created the Delete function to delete the data from the table.

I want to delete data based on where condition. 
I want to dynamically create the where condition for the 30 tables. i have 6 column that will be part of the where clause

The twist is 
one table will have 2 column as a condition, 
other may have 3 condition and 
another table  may have  all the 6 condition condition . 
what i know is there will be maximum of 6 condition in the delete statment and these columns are fixed

Let me explain this to you
For 1 Table it is

`Delete from table1 where act ='A' AND LE ='C'`

For 2 table it is

`Delete from Table 2 where act ='A' AND LE ='C' and gors='G'`

So for different table i will have different where clause.

I am thinking of creating a function which will dynamically create the where clause in the query.

I will be storing the table name in the variable based on user selection on the form and
then would be having an if Condition .

```
   if tnbl = table1
    then where condition =  act ='A' AND LE ='C' 
    Else if if tnbl = table2
    then where condition =  act ='A' AND LE ='C' and gors='G'
```

I dont like the above way of creating the where clause becasue if i have 30 tables i would require 30 if Else clause`

It is not at all a good way

Any suggestion of how i can implement it in most effective way.

Help much Appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: Add a table which relates table name to where clause? Or use a `Select Case` approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're going to get around this being somewhat complicated when you're talking about 30 tables with different requirements, but you could simplify the statement if you can find similarities between the tables' requirements.

Taking your examples above, there's an overlap between what you want to delete in table1 and table2.  If you write some code that takes those individual elements and adds them to a string that you later use as an SQL 'Execute' command, you might save some time.

For example, Table1 needs *"act ='A' AND LE ='C'"* to be part of the WHERE clause and Table2 requires *"gors='G'"* to be added as well.  Let's say *"act ='A' AND LE ='C'"* are paired in every circumstance where either one would appear in a WHERE statement, so that could be a single element (Element A) and the *"gors='G'"* could be another (Element B).

When you're creating your SQL String for execution, you tell the function that if Table1 is selected, we add Element A to a 'CombinedElements' string.  If Table2 is selected, we add *both* Elements A and B.

After you've selected the Elements, you assemble a SQL String that puts it all together:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM " & TableSelected & " WHERE " & CombinedElements & "; ", dbFailOnError
```

Doing it this way might make it a little easier to deal with and give you flexibility to add more tables in the future if need be.  Also, with a little bit of care, this method could be adjusted to allow multiple tables to be selected at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use select case in Excel VBA. first use connection string to connect with MSAccess by using ADODB object and using recorset and opening a connection 
Thencreate a dropdown which will have all 30 table list, then store that value in a variable, then use select case to define each condition for every table. under each case give delete query